# Drupal view gives page title for search (Search Product category for...)

Tags: drupal, view, title

I created a webshop using Drupal 7 and commerce kickstart. After making some modifications and building some views i noticed the product category view not passing the right taxonomy term as page title but is see the text "Search Product category for..".

I think I am missing out on a setting or something. How do I disable the search title and start using the views title.

For reference read this post: https://drupal.org/node/1250928 it gives lots of info on this matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this was caused by not (or not correct) inhereting contextual filters from one view to another.